# SWING JTable, cell start to edit event

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable and these cells of it are editable, there are any ways to handle the "cell start to edit" event in order that I can display a message when users start to  edit a cell.

Answer (score 7):

If this were my code, I'd start by trying to override the TableEditor's `getTableCellEditorComponent` method. Inside of the override, I'd call the method that I want to call when editing starts, and then I'd call the super's `getTableCellEditorComponent` method inside the override.

You can find out more details on how to use custom cell editors (since this is what you need to do) at the [JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: can you give me an example for the anwser, please ?

Comment: @NessajNguyen: the JTable tutorial will explain how to create and use a custom cell editor. Please check the link that I've provided in my edited answer.

Answer (score 6):

Add a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `JTable`:

```
//
//  Implement the PropertyChangeListener interface
//
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
    {
        //  A cell has started/stopped editing

        if ("tableCellEditor".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
        {
            if (table.isEditing())
                // code for editing started;
            else
                // code for editing stopped;
        }
    }
```